# Post Unsupported MediaType

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

When i call method above i recive error `415 (Unsupported Media Type)`

In angular

```
  this.reservationService.createReservation(this.reservation).subscribe(res =>{
    console.log(res);
  });
```

reservation is ReservationDto type

```
export class ReservationDto {
    email: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    phoneNumber: string;
    reservationDate: string;
    id_seance: number;
    user_id: number;
}
```

in reservation.service

```
  public createReservation(reservationDTO: ReservationDto) {
    return this.http.post(ReservationService.RESERVATION_URL + ReservationService.CREATE_RESERVATION, ReservationService.CREATE_RESERVATION);
  }
```

In java 
my Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="reservation")
@Data
public class Reservation {

    public Reservation() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer id;

    private java.time.LocalDate reservationDate;

    @NonNull
    private String email;

    @NonNull
    private String firstName;

    @NonNull
    private String lastName;

    @Column(length=9)
    @NonNull
    private String phoneNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_seance")
    private Seance reservationSeance;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User userReservation;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "reservations")
    private List<Seat> seats = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

In Service

```
@Transactional
public Reservation createReservation(ReservationDTO reservationDTO) {
    Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
    reservation.setEmail(reservationDTO.getEmail());
    reservation.setFirstName(reservationDTO.getFirstName());
    reservation.setLastName(reservationDTO.getLastName());
    reservation.setPhoneNumber(reservationDTO.getPhoneNumber());
reservation.setReservationDate(LocalDate.parse(reservationDTO.getReservationDate()));
    return reservationRepository.saveAndFlush(reservation);
}
```

And Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createEvent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Reservation createReservation(@RequestBody ReservationDTO reservationDTO) {
    return reservationService.createReservation(reservationDTO);
}
```

I try add row to databse in Service.java don't passed whole field. My Question is that i must set id reservation manually or it can be done autmoatically? I have in Entity field from  another Entity as User, Seance and I must findById() whole object or only need Id. And how avoid error 415.

Comment: Assuming you're posting json from your UI then you need to add `consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` to your `@RequestMapping`. Do the same for `produces=`. Also `import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;` to bring in the definition.

Comment: When i check Request Header i have Content-Type text/plain

Comment: If your actual content is json then change your sender javascript to set the content type to application/json because text/plain will not be recognised and automatically parsed on the Spring side.

Comment: When i add consumes to @RequestMapping don't help and  I that using a string as body makes Angular assume 'text/plain' as content type instead of the default 'application/json'. I try in front side add content-type as application/json